# Using ng-model="search" typeahead= to enter existing tags and repeat after a choice?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, meanjs

I am trying to use `ng-model="search" typeahead="..."` to get a list of tags. As soon as the user starts typing I want to display all the ones that match. Once a user chooses one, enter that string to the input form, put a `", "` and basically repeat the processes.

This is what I have in the HTML view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="tags">Tags</label>
    <section ng-controller="TagsController" ng-init="find()">
        <textarea type="text" ng-model="search" typeahead="tag as tag.name for tag in tags | filter:$viewValue " class="form-control" typeahead-on-select="" placeholder="Create a new tag or chose an existing one. Seperate tags with commas."></textarea>
    </section>
</div>
```

This is my front front end Tag Controller.

```
// Tags controller
angular.module('tags').controller('TagsController', [
  '$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Articles', 'Tags', '$filter',
  function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Articles, Tags, $filter) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;

    // Create new Tags
    $scope.find = function() {
      $scope.tags = Tags.query();
    };
  }
]);
```

This is going to be a form used to create an article, and ultimately I want that field for inputs to be strings separated by commas.

With what I have right now, start typing in the Tag field, a list of matching tags pops up. If I choose one, it enters it in the field and that is it. If I put a comma or anything after it does not search anymore.

The very same concept used here in **stackoverflow** . Start typing at the  "Tags" field, matching tags come up, choose one, start typing second tag, the process repeats.

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle of your question with some dummy data, So we could manage a solution for you.

Comment: do you need something like that http://plnkr.co/edit/juqoNOt1z1Gb349XabQ2?p=preview

Comment: This is similar to what I am looking for, but it does not give me the option to create, or enter new tags. For example in the colors (Array of String) there are two colors there initially Blue, Red. If i type Green, yeah it adds that, but if i type "hello" it does not add that to the array.

Comment: I want it to be: Selected: ["Blue","Red","Green", "hello"]. And after it has typed "hello", if the user types "Ye" the Yellow should pop up and if selected the  string should be: ["Blue","Red","Green", "hello" , "Yellow"]